# How to merge 2 values of variables apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send a email with a formatted list of data (datalist1, datalist2, datalist3) on it. The list of data has a format that I want to make, but when I merge the 3 datalist using "push" into 1 array (merge) and send by email, the format only works for the first data (datalist1). If you guys know the problem or show the other way to achive it, It can be really helpful. Thank you 

**The sample input value of variable 'data':**

[image]

**The Expected Result that I want:**

[image]

**The Result that I got now: (The Problem)**

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');

  var [_, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var arr1 = [];
  var arr2 = [];
  var arr3 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == 'First') {
      arr1.push([data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][0], data[i][3]]);
    }
    if (data[i][0] == 'Second') {
      arr2.push([data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][0], data[i][3]]);
    }
    if (data[i][0] == 'Third') {
      arr3.push([data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][0], data[i][3]]);
    }
  }

  var merge = [];
  var datalist1;
  var datalist2;
  var datalist3;

  for (var y = 0; y < arr1.length; y++) {
    if (arr1[y][2] == 'First') {
      if (y == 0) {
        datalist1 = "First" + "\n" + "- " + arr1[y];
      } else {
        datalist1 = datalist1 + "\n" + "- " + arr1[y]
      }

    }
  }

  for (var y = 0; y < arr2.length; y++) {
    if (arr2[y][2] == 'Second') {
      if (y == 0) {
        datalist2 = "Second" + "\n" + "- " + arr2[y];
      } else {
        datalist2 = datalist2 + "\n" + "- " + arr2[y]
      }

    }
  }

  for (var y = 0; y < arr3.length; y++) {
    if (arr3[y][2] == 'Third') {
      if (y == 0) {
        datalist3 = "Third" + "\n" + "- " + arr3[y];
      } else {
        datalist3 = datalist3 + "\n" + "- " + arr3[y]
      }

    }
  }
  console.log(datalist1);
  console.log(datalist2);
  console.log(datalist3);


  merge.push(datalist1, datalist2, datalist3);
  //merge.sort();
  console.log(merge);
  var email = '@gmail.com'
  var Subject = "data";
  var Message = "Hello, \n" + "\n" +
    "This is a data message to let you know\n" + "\n" +
    "Here is the list of data: \n" + datalist1 + 
    "\n" + datalist2 + "\n" + datalist3 + "\n";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, Subject, Message);

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Format that I want make in the email:` and `Format after push into 1 array and send by email:` and your script and your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, can you provide the sample input values of `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` and the sample output value of `merge` you expect?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. I also want to apologize with my english skill too. The output value of 'merge' is on the 'Format after push into 1 array and send by email:' and the values of 'arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3' is a filtered data for grouping the datalist by 'First', 'Second', 'Third'

Comment: The expect value that I want for 'merge' is on the 'Format that I want make in the email:'

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand `The output value of 'merge' is on the 'Format after push into 1 array and send by email:' and the values of 'arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3' is a filtered data for grouping the datalist by 'First', 'Second', 'Third'` and `The expect value that I want for 'merge' is on the 'Format that I want make in the email:'`.

Comment: Sorry @Tanaike, the output of 'merge' right now is 'Format after push into 1 array and send by email:' and The output that I expect to happen is 'Format that I want make in the email:'. I already edit the question with the source value of arr1, arr2, arr3.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. In this case, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input value of `data` and the sample output value of `merge` you expect?

Comment: Sorry for my poor skill @Tanaike, I already edited my question again, I hope It can help to understand my problem

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. When your showing sample Spreadsheet is used as `data`, can you provide your expected values?

Comment: Maybe, I can send you the sample spreadsheet link so It can be much easier to discuss? @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Maybe, I can send you the sample spreadsheet link so It can be much easier to discuss?`, in this case, I cannot understand your expected result from your question. So, I asked about your expected result using your showing image of the sample Spreadsheet. So, can you provide your expected result instead of the sample Spreadsheet? I think that the reason that I cannot understand your expected result is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've just edited my question again with image of the expected result that I want

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation. (Following images are from your question.)

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]

#### Modification points:

- From your showing an image of the sample Spreadsheet, it supposes that `data` is `[["First", "low", "medium", "high"], ["Second", "medium", "low", "high"], ["First", "low", "high", "medium"], ["Second", "medium", "low", "high"], ["First", "low", "high", "medium"], ["Third", "low", "high", "medium"]]`.
- When `data` is used for your script, `arr1`, `arr2`, and `arr3` are `[["low","medium","high"],["low","high","medium"],["low","high","medium"]]`, `[["medium","low","high"],["medium","low","high"]]` and `[["low","high","medium"]]`, respectively. In this case, `arr1[i][0] == 'First'`, `arr2[i][0] == 'Second'` and `arr3[i][0] == 'Third'` are always `false`. By this, all values of `datalist1`, `datalist2`, `datalist3` are `null`.

  - From this situation and your question, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script.

From the above situation, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script using the above value of `data` and your expected result of ``.

#### Sample script:

```js
const data = [["First", "low", "medium", "high"], ["Second", "medium", "low", "high"], ["First", "low", "high", "medium"], ["Second", "medium", "low", "high"], ["First", "low", "high", "medium"], ["Third", "low", "high", "medium"]]; // This is from your showing image of sample Spreadsheet.
const order = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']; // This is from your script.

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const i1 = order.indexOf(a[0]);
  const i2 = order.indexOf(b[0]);
  const len = data.length;
  return 1 * ((i1 > -1 ? i1 : len) - (i2 > -1 ? i2 : len));
});
const merged = sorted.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => {
  if (o.temp != a) {
    o.merged.push(a);
    o.temp = a;
  }
  o.merged.push(`- ${b.join(",")}`);
  return o;
}, { merged: [], temp: "" }).merged.join("\n");
console.log(merged)
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
First
- low,medium,high
- low,high,medium
- low,high,medium
Second
- medium,low,high
- medium,low,high
Third
- low,high,medium
```

#### Note:

- If you want a script for retrieving values from Spreadsheet, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    const data = sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  ```

#### References:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. I'll be back with the result

Comment: Sorry @Tanaike, would you like to explain the 'order'?

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. About `Would you like to explain the 'order'?`, in this case, using `order`, the custom sort is run at `const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {,,,})`. By this, `data` is converted to `[["First","low","medium","high"],["First","low","high","medium"],["First","low","high","medium"],["Second","medium","low","high"],["Second","medium","low","high"],["Third","low","high","medium"]]`. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Firstly, I want to apologize with my knowledge. If I want to take just some of the column and not all of the column, how can I do that?

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. About your new question of `If I want to take just some of the column and not all of the column, how can I do that?`, I would like to support you. But, first, I would like to recommend resolving your initial question. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I've just resolve my question @Tanaike

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. About your new question of `If I want to take just some of the column and not all of the column, how can I do that?`, I would like to support you. In this case, in order to think of a solution, it is required to know the input and output values you expect. So, if you need an answer to your new question, please consider providing the sample input and output values you expect. By this, it will help think of a solution.

Comment: Okay, I have to edit my question again right?

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. About `Okay, I have to edit my question again right?`, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. Because, when your question was updated by including a new question, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.

Comment: Okay then, I'll post it right away

Comment: I've just post the new question