# How to take only a few of the column and not all of the column (Extended Question)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is the extended from the previous question.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75131230/18537212)

Now, I want to try modify the answer. I want to take only some the column and not all of them. How can I modify that? Thank you.

**The data source:**
[image]

**The Expected result:**

[image]

**Here is the previous question's answer:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');

  var [_, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const order = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
    const i1 = order.indexOf(a[0]);
    const i2 = order.indexOf(b[0]);
    const len = data.length;
    return 1 * ((i1 > -1 ? i1 : len) - (i2 > -1 ? i2 : len));
  });
  const merged = sorted.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (o.temp != a) {
      o.merged.push(a);
      o.temp = a;
    }
    o.merged.push(`- ${b.join(",")}`);
    return o;
  }, { merged: [], temp: "" }).merged.join("\n");

  console.log(merged)
  var email = ''
  var Subject = "data";
  var Message = "Hello ", \n" + "\n" +
    "Here is the list of data:\n" + merged + "\n" + "\n";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, Subject, Message);
}
```

Comment: In your showing image, the 1st column has no values of `'First', 'Second', 'Third'`. By this, the sort cannot be done. From this situation, I'm worried that you have miscopied your sample image. How about this?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, Sorry for the late reply. In my case, this is the real situation that I have right now. I have done the grouping but still looking the way to sort it. I have a different sheet that store the 'Data Type' column, can it help to find another way to solve this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `In my case, this is the real situation that I have right now. I have done the grouping but still looking the way to sort it`, in this case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? And, can you provide the detail of `I want to take only some the column`?

Comment: So from my question 'I want to take only some the column' meaning I want to get some of the column and not all of them. Previous answer was take all of the column and not some of them. I want to take Column 6, Column 2, Column 3, Column 7, and Column 5 to as Expected result's data (Like the 'Expected Result' that I provide on the question)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood about `I want to take only some the column`. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding @Tanaike, do you want the link of the sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `do you want the link of the sample spreadsheet?`, I thought that in your question, it might be required to test the modified script. But, from your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not your expected result, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Now, I noticed that you have updated your question by adding one more script. My proposed modification is for your 1st script. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var [_, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var columns = [6, 2, 3, 7, 5]; // This is from your comment of "I want to take Column 6, Column 2, Column 3, Column 7, and Column 5 to as Expected result's data".
columns.unshift(2);
var [_, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
data = data.map(r => columns.map(f => r[f - 1]));
```

#### References:

- [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Tanaike. I have been struggling with this problem for 3 days and It's finally have the expected result that I want. I really appreciate with your help and I apologize for my explanation skill.

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. In this case, I cannot test the script using your expected values. So I have been worried whether I could correctly understand your situation. But, from your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I have some a minor question @Tanaike. If I want to add another '\n' so It can look more like 'The Expected Result' image. Where should I add it?

Comment: @Asking Bob About your new question of `I have some a minor question @Tanaike. If I want to add another '\n' so It can look more like 'The Expected Result' image. Where should I add it? `, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: I want to make it look like the image of expected result on my question. The result that I have right now don't have any spacing between First, Second, Third

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `I want to make it look like the image of expected result on my question. The result that I have right now don't have any spacing between First, Second, Third`, I cannot still understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Nevermind, I just got the solution to add '\n' in the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.